# Android: How to set pointer towards file through filepath

Tags: android

In Android, I want to create a pointer that points to already existing file by way of its filepath.

For example, my pseudo-code:

```
String path = "file/directory/filename";
File ptr = File's pointed to by the path
```

The Android documentation only provides methods with which one can create a new file through a file path, but I just want a File object that only points to an already existing File.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
String path = "file/directory/filename";
File ptr  = new File(path);

// check If file exists.
if(ptr.exists()) {
   // Your code Here if file exists                                             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File(path);
```

f points to a virtual file , if the file doesnt exist, writing anything to it, will either create it or cause a system crash , depending on the type of content you are writing to it.

deleting a file that doesnt exist will also fail, so any operation with files must be encapsulated with try catch for IOException

see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

also on android's new Kitkat you explicity have to request the permission to `READ_EXTRANL_STORAGE` if you want to read, and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you want to write